# pthread_join free(): invalid pointer error

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, pthreads

I've got such a piece of code:

```
void *write_parallel(void *num_for_chunk) {

    struct rusage *sum = (struct rusage*) malloc(sizeof(struct rusage));
    if(sum==NULL) {
        perror("Writing buffer: ");
    }

    sum->ru_utime.tv_sec = 0;
    sum->ru_utime.tv_usec = 0;
    sum->ru_stime.tv_sec = 0;
    sum->ru_stime.tv_usec = 0;

    pthread_exit(sum);
}
```

I've got a thread table:

```
pthread_t* thread_table = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*num_of_threads);
```

I'm creating a thread with:

```
pthread_create(thread_table+(sizeof(pthread_t)*j),NULL,write_parallel,&num_for_chunk);
```

And join with:

```
pthread_join(*(thread_table+(sizeof(pthread_t)*j)),&part_res);
```

When I run program I've got:

```
*** Error in `./write_test': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f6b6e44a700 ***
```

I think that there's a problem when thread disappears and I want to get a value that was passed to pthread_exit, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `thread_table` to be declare as array of `pthread_t`:

```
pthread_t thread_table[<some positive integer>];
```

or

```
pthread_t * thread_table = calloc(<some positive integer>, sizeof(*thread_table);
```

just remove the `sizeof(pthread_t)` when accessing it's elements.

So

```
pthread_create(thread_table+(sizeof(pthread_t)*j), ...
```

would become

```
pthread_create(thread_table+j, ...
```

And

```
pthread_join(*(thread_table+(sizeof(pthread_t)*j)), ...
```

would become

```
pthread_join(*(thread_table + j), ...
```

**Background**: Incrementing a (non `void *`) pointer `T p` by `1` moves the pointer to point to the **next** element of type `T`. That means the the pointer is incremented `sizeof(T)` or, which is equal, `sizeof(*p)` bytes.

---

A simpler and more straight forward approach to access an array's elements would be to use the `[]` operator like so:

```
pthread_create(&thread_table[j], ...

...

pthread_join(thread_table[j], ...
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post it at first. I have to dynamically allocate this table. I've edited my question.

Comment: @WojciechReszelewski: You **also** can access elements in a dynamical allocated array by using the `[]` operator.